# How to make a jar with a thrid party dependency jar packed with it in manifest (without any ide)

Tags: java

If I use `-cp` then I can't use the jar in other directories or distribute it. Is it possible to make an executable jar file with the dependency packed into it using manifest and without using gradle/maven and make it possible to distribute just one jar file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create jar with all dependency by unziping classes from all jars to one folder (creating `MANIFEST.FM` if needed) and use `jar` command to create new jar. Details can be found [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-how-to-create-executable-fatjar-without-ide).